# Laptop wont boot from cd/harddrive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, compact-disc

Problem:
Wont boot.

Laptop starts, BIOS menu is accesible. Windows 7 is already installed on it, but wont boot.
And then it just keeps showing black screen, with a flashing white: _

So something is wrong with the harddrive?
But also when i put in a cd, and set CD as the first boot, and i put in a linux/windows cd, it doesnt do anything, and shows only the: _

Should i buy a new hard disk? Or try something else to determine whats wrong?

Can something be wrong with mbr or something? I dont know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting from a USB? Unetbootin is a handy program for creating such bootable usb's

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/